# Laravel DB::Raw not working as expected

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am forming the query below:

```
SELECT *, ACOS( SIN( RADIANS( `latitude` ) ) * SIN( RADIANS('17.4073331') ) + COS( RADIANS( `latitude` ) )* COS( RADIANS('17.4073331')) * COS( RADIANS( `longitude` ) - RADIANS('78.3802307'))) * 6380 AS distance 
FROM bbq_branches_by_city 
HAVING distance <= 20
```

I am doing like below in laravel:

```
DB::table('bbq_branches_by_city')
  ->select(DB::raw("*, ACOS( SIN( RADIANS( `latitude` ) ) * SIN( RADIANS($lat) ) + COS( RADIANS( `latitude` ) )* COS( RADIANS($lat)) * COS( RADIANS( `longitude` ) - RADIANS($long))) * 6380 AS distance"))
  ->havingRaw("distance <= 20")
  ->get();
```

Can you let me know where I am mistaking?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do you get an error or an incorrect output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DB::table('bbq_branches_by_city')
     -> select(["*",DB::raw("ACOS( SIN( RADIANS( `latitude` ) ) * SIN( RADIANS($lat) ) + COS( RADIANS( `latitude` ) )* COS( RADIANS($lat)) * COS( RADIANS( `longitude` ) - RADIANS($long))) * 6380 AS distance")])
     ->havingRaw("distance<=20")
     ->get();
```

Just make the select as **array** like `['*','distance']`

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code, based on [running-queries](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/database#running-queries):

```
$data = DB::select('select *,ACOS( SIN( RADIANS( `latitude` ) ) * SIN( RADIANS('17.4073331') ) + COS( RADIANS( `latitude` ) )* COS( RADIANS('17.4073331')) * COS( RADIANS( `longitude` ) - RADIANS('78.3802307'))) * 6380 AS distance from bbq_branches_by_city having distance<=20');
```